# Saving regex matches into an array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, url, save

I get an url string as input into constructor of Url class and I would like to parse it with my regex into parts like **protocol, host, port, path, query, fragmet** where some parts could be missing. For example I can get `https://domain:80/path` or I could get `https://domain/path?query#fragment` And I need an arrays like this :

`["https", "://", "domain", ":80", "path", "", "", "", ""]`

or

`["https", "://", "domain", "", "path", "?", "query", "#", "fragment"]`

Each substring in an array should be one group from regex using matcher.

Later I will make getters which will give me specific parts of this url, or I will be simplifying the path in case of /./ or /../ is in it.
**The problem right now is how can I save this into an array which I can later wok with.**

Comment: Why don't you just assign it to a URL class and then use the builtin methods to pull off what you want?

Comment: Cause I kinda cant use built in functions :D

Comment: Are you saying  you can use the build in capabilities (i.e. methods) of a `regex` parser but are not permitted to use the methods of a class that was made just for this purpose?  That doesn't really make much sense.  What is forcing this limitation on you?

Comment: Yea it doesn't give sense to me either but it's an exercise where it's not allowed, I should do it that way.

Comment: Then you need to check out the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and then try some examples on either the URL or something else.  If you have problems, edit your question with your attempts and someone will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

> ```
> \\b(https?)(://)(?:w{3}\\.)?([^\\s/:]+)(:\\d{2,6})?/([^?/\\s]+)(\\?)?(\\w+)?#?(\\w+)?\\b
> ```

might work OK to some extent.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\b(https?)(://)(?:w{3}\\.)?([^\\s/:]+)(:\\d{2,6})?/([^?/\\s]+)(\\?)?(\\w+)?#?(\\w+)?\\b";
        final String string = "https://domain:80/path or I could get https://domain/path?query#fragment https://www.domain:80/path or I could get http://domain/path?query#fragment ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: https://domain:80/path
Group 1: https
Group 2: ://
Group 3: domain
Group 4: :80
Group 5: path
Group 6: null
Group 7: null
Group 8: null
Full match: https://domain/path?query#fragment
Group 1: https
Group 2: ://
Group 3: domain
Group 4: null
Group 5: path
Group 6: ?
Group 7: query
Group 8: fragment
Full match: https://www.domain:80/path
Group 1: https
Group 2: ://
Group 3: domain
Group 4: :80
Group 5: path
Group 6: null
Group 7: null
Group 8: null
Full match: http://domain/path?query#fragment
Group 1: http
Group 2: ://
Group 3: domain
Group 4: null
Group 5: path
Group 6: ?
Group 7: query
Group 8: fragment
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LSPk4f/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LSPk4f/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]